# Close a screen using an activity

Tags: pega

I have a bit of a complex situation in my application. In my flow, I have to support a back-to-back assignment as well as a normal assignment.

When a user hit submit from the screen, depending on the input, either back-to-back assignment or the normal assignment will follow.And both paths work fine.

My question is,since I have enabled "Look for an assignment to perform" in flow action, even when normal assignment is selected, screen does not get closed when the user hit submit. So I have to find a way to close the screen forcefully.

Do anyone of you know a way( Data transform/Activity) to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the Javascript APIs provided by Pega for this. Do you want the entire browser window to close or just the tab to close? You can try embedding a script in your section and execute it close the window or screen.